# Does using two hashmaps make an algorithm O(n squared)?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, big-o, space-complexity

I'm trying to figure out the Big O time and space complexity of the algorithm below.

I think that the time complexity is O(n) where n is the size of the larger HashMap. My understanding is that the 3 loops make it O(3n) but then you remove the constant to get O(n). And that HashMaps(in Java at least) are O(1) for put and get operations.

I think that the space complexity is O(n) where n is the size of the HashMap.

Here's my problem though. There are 2 HashMaps. So, does that make the space complexity n x n = n squared?

Or is it O(2n), which becomes O(n)?

```
HashMap<String,Integer> magazineWordOccurrences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < magazine.length; i++)
{
    if (magazineWordOccurrences.containsKey(magazine[i]))
    {
        magazineWordOccurrences.put(magazine[i], magazineWordOccurrences.get(magazine[i]) + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        magazineWordOccurrences.put(magazine[i], 1);
    }
}

HashMap<String,Integer> noteWordOccurrences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < note.length; i++)
{
    if (noteWordOccurrences.containsKey(note[i]))
    {
        noteWordOccurrences.put(note[i], noteWordOccurrences.get(note[i]) + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        noteWordOccurrences.put(note[i], 1);
    }
}

boolean match = true;
for (String key: noteWordOccurrences.keySet())
{
    if (magazineWordOccurrences.containsKey(key))
    {
        if (!(magazineWordOccurrences.get(key) >= noteWordOccurrences.get(key)))
        {
            match = false;
            System.out.println("No");
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        match = false;
        System.out.println("No");
        break;
    }
}

if (match)
{
    System.out.println("Yes");
}
```

Comment: Complexity is *not* related to the number of loops but to the amount of work done !

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter that there are two `HashMap`s.

What matters is that you have 3 loops, which are not nested. The iteration of each loop takes constant time, so the entire running time of each loop depends on the number of iterations.

Hence the total running time is O(n), where `n` is the largest of `magazine.length`, `note.length` and `noteWordOccurrences.keySet().size()`.

The space complexity is also linear as long as you have a constant number of data structures (2 `Map`s in your case) and each one of them requires `O(n)` space.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.